# Django Rest Framework - ManyToMany relationship through intermediate model

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and have just started to learn the basics. I have some questions about how to structure the code, how relationships should be written, and where the business logic should live.

**I have written a simple app that should do the following:**

1. Store Group and Member entities in a database.
2. Maintain a many-to-many relationship between groups and members, as well as member role specific to each group.
3. To create or update a group it should be possible send a request with the json structure shown below.

   ```
   {
     "name": "My group 1",
     "members": [
       { "id": 1, "role": "Leader" },
       { "id": 2, "role": "Regular" }
     ]
   }
   ```

**Questions about the code**

1. Am I re-inventing the wheel with the custom update/create code in the GroupSerializer? Does what I'm trying to do already exist in Django and I have just not found the right approach?
2. Is the update/create logic in the GroupSerializers misplaced? Should this be in the views.py file?
3. In serializers.py, line 23, is there a better way than using "source=groupmember_set". I feel dirty hardcoding this string.
   In additional comments are of course welcome.

I appreciate any feedback that can improve the code and my knowledge further!

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Member, blank=True, related_name='groups', through="GroupMember")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.member.name + " " + self.group.name + " - " + self.role
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Group, Member, GroupMember
from django.db import transaction


class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'groups')


class GroupMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='member.id')
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='member.name')

    class Meta:
        model = GroupMember
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'role')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = GroupMemberSerializer(source="groupmember_set", many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

    @transaction.atomic
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Ignore the fact that i delete and replace. Will diff in the future
        GroupMember.objects.filter(group=instance).delete()
        members = self.initial_data.get("members")
        for member in members:
            id = member.get("id")
            role = member.get("role")
            new_member = Member.objects.get(pk=id)
            GroupMember(group=instance, member=new_member, role=role).save()

        instance.__dict__.update(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        group = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if "members" in self.initial_data:
            members = self.initial_data.get("members")
            for member in members:
                id = member.get("id")
                role = member.get("role")
                member_instance = Member.objects.get(pk=id)
                GroupMember(group=group, member=member_instance, role=role).save()
        group.save()
        return project
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from models import Group, Member
from serializers import GroupSerializer, MemberSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer


class MemberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this here.  It's the first working example I've been able to find on the net for posting nested data with a through model.  Mostly working anyway.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for this code snippet! I have been wondering what I am doing wrong for hours until I found this example!

Comment: You don't have to handle nested [representations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54222988/52499).

Answer (score 4):

[Django-organizations](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-organizations/) is a great way to do this, if you didn't want to reinvent the wheel. Comes with many things I assume you would need in the future out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it wasn't the organization domain specifically that I needed a solution for. More how to implement the relation in general.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `source=groupmember_set` with `source=groups` (the related_name of the ManyToMany field). I think it is a little bit cleaner and easier to understand.

One thing I don't understand is, why are you using `model = Project` in your `GroupSerializer` class?